# Is there a way to move the android Honeycomb action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I like how the Android 3.0+ action bar looks, but I don't want it to be on top of the screen. Is there a way to move it to the bottom or to the side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to do so. At least not using public APIs. You could easily find a way to do it but your app would be inconsistent with other apps and likely to break with future updates of the OS.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have some luck if you delve deep enough into [ActionBarSherlock's](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) source code. Since that library creates an ActionBar for pre-HC devices, you may be able to just change the position where it appears. This isn't exactly the answer you were looking for, but it just might be able to solve your problem.

Comment: It wouldn't work in 3.0+ versions while ActionBarSherlock uses standart API for them